# Change the fill color in front direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on creating cylinder using canvas and I have coded for to fill the cylinder (animate) based on the percentage.

When I enter value in the textbox it start fill in back wards (Fill). But it has to fill (Green) in front direction direction how the top of the cylinder look like.

If we change the cy value can direction of fill will change.  Any Suggestion / solution

Here is the Draw Cylinder code

```
function draw() 
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); 
    // draw grey main cylinder
   drawCylinder(cx, cy, width, height, height / 8, '#b1b1b1', '#000');
    // draw green progression cylinder
    var currHeight = someValue * height / 100;
    var newCenterY =  cy - currHeight / 2 + height / 2;     
    //Here is where green fill starts   
    drawCylinder(cx, newCenterY, width, currHeight, height / 4, '#81ae45', null);
    // draw (fill and stroke) the top of the progression cylinder
    drawCylinderTop(cx, newCenterY, width, 100, height / 4, '#9a9a9a', null);
   // stroke the top of the main cylinder
}
```

Here is my code for draw cylinder

```
function drawCylinder(x, y, w, h, vRadius, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
var w2 = w / 2;
var h2 = h / 2;
var ytop = -h2;
var cpYtop = -h2 - vRadius;
var ybottom = h2;
var cpYbottom = h2 + vRadius;
ctx.save();     
ctx.translate(x, y);    
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(-w2, ytop);  
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop, w2, cpYtop, w2, ytop);
ctx.lineTo(w2, ybottom);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(w2, cpYbottom, -w2, cpYbottom, -w2, ybottom);
ctx.closePath();    
performDraw(fillStyle); 
ctx.restore();
```

}

If i try to change the bezierCurveTo in to static value still it was not changing.

I don't have reputation to put exact  output image what I want.

Here is the updated fiddle link.

I have modified the below line of  code

```
var newCenterY =  cy + currHeight / 2 + height / 2;
```

Previously it was

```
var newCenterY =  cy - currHeight / 2 + height / 2;
```

I am struggling to change the direction of fill color help needed.

Please do the needful.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/LyTt2/2/)

Thanks in advance
M

Comment: You have `<canvas>` in `<canvas>`. separate them.

Comment: Hi @MindaugasVečkys i have separated but still now working

Comment: fixed code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rAA8S/1/). now you can see curves.

Comment: hi @MindaugasVečkys thanks for sharing the  code but when i gave it in pixels it was displaying two times and can you suggest me how to change the directions of filling arc

Comment: hi @MindaugasVečkys thanks for sharing the  code but when i gave it in pixels for the curve. Curve was displaying two times and can you suggest me how to change the directions of filling arc

Comment: hi @MindaugasVečkys i got it how to remove two times curve can you suggest me how to change direction of the fill

Comment: You mean like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rAA8S/2/)?

Comment: hi if you see the curve direction it was facing us in the same way  color also need to fill now it's filling in opposite direction

Comment: hi @MindaugasVečkys if we change the value of x is that possible my position of filling direction will change can you suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added one more function two change the direction of filling

```
I have created one more function call drawCylinderprogress

function drawCylinderprogress(x, y, w, h, vRadius, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
var w2 = w / 2;
var h2 = h / 2;
var ytop = -h2;
var cpYtop = -h2 - vRadius;
var ybottom = h2;
var cpYbottom = h2 + vRadius;
ctx.save();     
ctx.translate(x, y);    
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(-w2, ytop);  
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/360, w2, cpYtop/360 , w2 , ytop); 
ctx.lineTo(w2, ybottom);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(w2, cpYbottom, -w2, cpYbottom, -w2, ybottom);
ctx.closePath();    
performDraw(fillStyle); 
ctx.restore();  
}
```

Regards
Mahadevan